# Cygwin OpenSSH server does not respond after first command from PHP (Using phpseclib)

Tags: windows-server-2008, php, ssh, cygwin, cygwin-sshd

I got cygwin and sshd working fine. And there are no issues at all when using putty. It responds as expected even for multiple commands. But when using phpseclib , A response is received only for the first command. Subsequent commands are giving a blank reply. This is the script i am trying to execute -

http://pastebin.com/msMCef8q

And this is the log output of phpseclib- http://pastebin.com/ff3sfux7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it. The solution is posted on my stackoverflow post -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250370/cygwin-openssh-server-does-not-respond-after-first-command-from-php-using-phpse/28263746#28263746